# Lookup function to define two directions for same dataset

Tags: excel-formula, offset, vlookup

Hi I want to create a pivot table basen on the data below. In column Q ("Ver 00") I have places/cities in abbreviations. I want to determine how many trips there are in both directions; from "bast" to "drg" and then from "drg" to bast". The problem is that all the trips do not always start in "bast" and finish in "drg" and the other way around. Sometimes they fx start in "nbst" and finish in "drg". I am completely lost here. But how do I make a column that recognizes which direction is "IN" and which direction is "OUT" if I define "bast" => "drg" as "IN" and "drg" => "bast" as "OUT"? I am thinking that vlookup might be useful here (defining the two directions) but I don't know if this will solve the problem.

The column should look like column AG.

I've tried with this formula but it is not working:

```
=IF([@Batch]<>N3,IF([@Rank]<=7,IF(COUNT.IF(Inrng,[@[Ver 10]]),"In",IF([@Rank]>7,IF(COUNT.IF(Outrng,[@[Ver 10]]),"Out",)))),AR3)
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly: each Batch is a trip? So trip "2, XXZ" goes from "cht" to "drg"? And do you want to count all routes between all cities (or whatever these are), or just "bast" and "drg"?

Comment: Yes, batch=trip. I want to determine whether the trip is inbound ("IN") or outbound ("Out"). As far as I can see the only way to do this is by having to tables to compare the data to (a "inbound table" and a "outbound table"). I am not sure how to do this. A possible solution (but not entirely correct) would be to find the midpoint of the trip which is 7 (there are 14 stations/cities in total).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, if you can be sure "bast" or "drg" is included in every batch (trip), then all you need is to determine which one was first in the given trip.

To do this, I'll use a match functions. These will have to find the "bast" and the "drg" of the actual batch. To do this, I'll concatenate the "Batch" and "Ver 00 "columns, and search in them.

Then all I need to do is compare the positions, see which one was first.

See below:

[image: trips sample picture]

Use this formula in cell D2:

```
=IF(MATCH(A2&"bast",C:C,0)<MATCH(A2&"drg",C:C,0),"in","out")
```

Is this closer to what you need? :)

---

### Added new method for missing "bast" or "drg" cases:

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH([@Batch]&"bast",[Batch&Ver 00],0)-MATCH([@Batch],[Batch],0)=0,"in","out"),IF(MATCH([@Batch]&"drg",[Batch&Ver 00],0)-MATCH([@Batch],[Batch],0)=0,"out","in"))
```

Note that I didn't do this in one go. I have used 5 helper columns, and did it step-by-step first. I recommend this method for complex calculations.

**What I'm doing here:**

Use a match to find the "bast" in the Batch.

```
MATCH([@Batch]&"bast",[Batch&Ver 00],0)
```

Use another match to find the first row of the actual Batch:

```
MATCH([@Batch],[Batch],0)
```

If these values are in the same row, then it is an "in", otherwise it is an "out":

```
IF(MATCH([@Batch]&"bast",[Batch&Ver 00],0)-MATCH([@Batch],[Batch],0)=0,"in","out")
```

Now, if this whole thing produces an error, that means "bast" can not be found. In this case, do the same search for "drg". This is what the iferror does:

```
IFERROR({...previous part...},IF(MATCH([@Batch]&"drg",[Batch&Ver 00],0)-MATCH([@Batch],[Batch],0)=0,"out","in"))
```

For reference, I here is another picture of the table I'm using, so that you understand the column names:

[image: BastDrg table]

Comment: Hmm, not exactly. I've added the expected outcome in the picture above in column AG. "In" or "out" should be added to every cell. Notice how the two ranges differ a little bit.

Comment: OK, I have edited my answer, see if it works for you!

Comment: Hmm, that's not always the case. I can't be sure :) See for example the batch starting in row 638. This doesn't start in "bast" nor "drg" but ends (luckily) in "bast". Sometimes they they start or end in one of them but they follow the pattern in Lnrng or Outrng.

Comment: And why have you created a the new column C?

Comment: Your formula works perfeclty when the batch contains "bast" AND "drg" but comes with "#I/T" whenever only one of them is contained in the batch.

Comment: Do you understand column C now? It is used to be able to search using 2 columns. [See here for more info - look for Concatenate method](http://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-on-two-or-more-criteria-columns/)

Comment: Well, you will need to add an iferror or two. If one of the cities can not be found, how do we know if it is an "IN" or an "OUT"? Just add iferror functions. Or do you expect me to do **all** the work for you? ;)

Comment: I understand C now. vacip, thank you for your patience and help. I'm not expecting you to do all the work, just asking for a helping hand which I appreciate a lot. I've tried adding two iferror functions outside the formula, like so: =IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(MATCH(N4&"bast";AE:AE;0)<MATCH(N4&"drg";AE:AE;0);"in";"out");"In");"Out").  But it just replaces "In" with the cells that used to have "#I/T". Don't know how to make it recognize "Out" as well. Tried adding the formula again just reversion the ">" and switching "In";"Out" with "Out":"In", but it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm, add the `iferror` inside then... Let me understand: if one of the destinations is missing, how do you know if it is an "IN" or an "OUT"? E.g. if only "drg" is present, and it is in row 4 of the Batch, is it an "IN" or an "OUT"?

Comment: Will try. Hmm, "bast" can only be in the first row of that batch and "drg" can only be on the last row of that batch if it is "IN" and the other way around for "OUT". Batch 59 in the uploaded picture would thus be a "OUT". Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Oh, I thought "bast" or "drg" can sometimes be in the middle of the batch too. If that is not the case, then it is relatively easy. Let me modify my answer in a minute.

Comment: Thank you very much! Tried to put the iferror-statement inside but didn't work.

Comment: Updated the answer, see if it helps.